# How do I resolve Windows 7 BSOD?

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod

My PC is running Windows 7.  I keep on getting the following BSOD (captured by a program I ran):

`On Thu 16/06/2016 16:58:33 GMT your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\061616-28392-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: win32k.sys (win32k+0x9C52) 
Bugcheck code: 0x3B (0xC0000005, 0xFFFFF96000069C52, 0xFFFFF880046DC230, 0x0)
Error: SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
file path: C:\Windows\system32\win32k.sys
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: Multi-User Win32 Driver
Bug check description: This indicates that an exception happened while executing a routine that transitions from non-privileged code to privileged code. 
This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem. 
The crash took place in a standard Microsoft module. Your system configuration may be incorrect. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver on your system that cannot be identified at this time.`

I do not recall downloading any dodgy software, updating drivers and have run an antivirus, spyware and malware programs as well as memory check, system file checker and chkdsk but nothing works.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Check this out - https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/980932

Comment: share this file: 061616-28392-01.dmp Also try to update the graphic card driver

Answer (score 0):

I did a sfc.exe scan and then downloaded malware bytes. It came up with 3 malware and many PUPs!! I then used spybot, which came up with a few more malware and PUPS!!! A memtest came up all fine. I restarted and my pc booted up w/o a bsod!! cheers for your help mate. Hope it works from now on. Have a nice weekend.
If all else fails i'll try the hotkey option.